# Can you choose how to sacrifice a creature if you are forced to?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an opponent, or anything else, makes me sacrifice a creature, and I have a Blood Host or something similar, can I choose to sacrifice the creature with the Blood Host?

Answer (score 3):

#### As a general rule - No.

In response to your opponent forcing a sacrifice, you can trigger your Blood Host's ability to the top of the stack.  This will then sacrifice your creature for the Blood Host, and then any other abilities remaining on the stack will resolve.  If this is the only creature that you have on the table, then the original sacrifice effect will be unresolved, exactly as if you were unable to sacrifice at the time the spell was cast.

If you have multiple other creatures on the field (As would be the case with your Blood Host being on the battlefield to begin with), you would have to chose another sacrifice for the initial effect.

Comment: Sacrifice doesn't target. The original effect causing you to sacrifice will still happen, and force you to sacrifice *another* creature, perhaps that Blood Host. (The only way this works is if you sacrificed your only creature, but the original effect still doesn't have an illegal target, it just resolves and doesn't do anything.)

Comment: If you have no other creatures the original sacrifice effect doesn't go unresolved, it resolves and does as much as it can (in this case nothing)

Comment: @Jefromi Sacrifice isn't an ability or spell, so yes, strictly speaking it doesn't target. However, things which cause a player to sacrifice creatures can absolutely target (http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+[target]+[creature%27s]+[controller]+[sacrifices]+[it]) in which case preemptively sacrificing the creature as part of a cost would be a reasonable reaction.

Comment: @AverageUnknown Things like that are far and away the exception, so my point definitely stands.

Comment: @Jefromi Agreed, just clarifying.